# Too many linked tables in a project

Tags: database, database-design, h2

I am using H2 Database for my Swing based Retail ERP (Point of Sale and Accounting) application.

We have two databases namely MainDB and CompanyDB in our application.

Main database to store all user information and company information. Whenever the user creates a Company, those data will be stored in company_table in  MainDB subsequently CompanyDB will be created for each company.

We have same master tables (around 60) in the MainDB and in CompanyDB. I will be inserting and updating to both databases, whenever any master created or edited in the application.

Very recently I came to know about Linked Table, which is very useful for me in many occasions.

My question is, if I create linked table for all masters in my CompanyDB

1. Can I have only linked table for all masters in CompanyDB?
2. I cannot reference foreign key for all transaction and other tables, as the master table is a linked table. Is it acceptable not to have foreign key relationship?
3. Creating around 60 linked tables, will reduce performance?

At present, I am very satisfied with the performance.

Please advise and throw some light on this.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Contact information can go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1826727/murugesan).

Answer (score 1):

1. Can I have only linked table for all masters in CompanyDB? Yes it is possible, even thought not very common. It really depends on the use case.
2. Is it acceptable not to have foreign key relationship? If you define a foreign key relationship between two tables in the MainDB then this will still be checked even if you do the updates in the CompanyDB. You can not have foreign key relationships across databases, but whether this is OK depends on the use case. For example in NoSQL databases, you typically don't have any foreign key relationships.
3. Creating around 60 linked tables, will reduce performance? The number of linked tables isn't a problem. But please note that each linked table individually is slower than a regular table. Whether this is acceptable depends on the use case.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. Can you suggest me any other way to implement the same, without using Linked table. ? At present, I am inserting to both the databases at the same time. Please let me know.

Comment: There are multiple ways to implement it. One approach would be to use a web service (using a RESTful API). But it really depends on the use case. I'm afraid this is the wrong forum to discuss possible architectures for your application.